# How to display SQL data into GUI list widget?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt4

I was wondering how to display information from an database table onto a listwidget or something similar. This is for a flashcard app, and the one questions is supposed to show at a time. Then when the click to reveal button is clicked the corresponding answer is supposed to show, but at the moment nothing is shown in the list widgets.
I don't understand why nothing is being shown in the GUI.

Here is my Code -

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui 
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys 
import flashcard
import os
import sqlite3 

class FlashCardApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, flashcard.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.questions = []
        self.answers = []
        self.currentQ = 0

        self.RevealAnswerBtn.clicked.connect(self.disA)

    def dispQ(self):
        print("display question {}".format(self.currentQ+1))

        self.listQuestionWidget.clear()
        if self.questions:
            self.listQuestionWidget.addItem(self.questions[self.currentQ])


    def disA(self):
        self.listAnswerWidget.clear()
        if self.answers:
            self.listAnswerWidget.addItem(self.answers[self.currentQ])

    def setData (self, questions, answers):
        self.questions = questions
        self.answers = answers

    def run(self):
        print ("start")

        self.currentQ = 0
        self.dispQ()




def main():
    questions = []
    answers = []

    connection = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute ("SELECT Question FROM Flashcards")
    resultq = c.fetchall()
    questions.append(resultq)
    c.execute ("SELECT Answer FROM Flashcards")
    resulta = c.fetchall()
    answers.append(resulta)
    connection.close()

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = FlashCardApp()
    form.setData(questions,answers)
    form.run()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but then i get this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 63, in main
    form.run()
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 41, in run
    self.dispQ()
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 25, in dispQ
    self.listQuestionWidget.addItem(self.questions[self.currentQ])
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QListWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QListWidget.addItem(str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

Comment: `form.run` or `form.run()`, typo??

Comment: It comes back with an error if I do - TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QListWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QListWidget.addItem(str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 63, in main
    form.run()
  File "C:/Users/joe gorsuch/OneDrive/A-Level/Computer Science/Computer Science Project/Program/Login Form/Ui/1.py", line 41, in run
    self.dispQ()

Comment: any idea why this has happend?

Comment: @Joseph. [addItem**s**](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#addItems).